# Have any Force-sensitives ever produced "non-Force-sensitive" offspring?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Canon or EU question — Have any Force-sensitives ever produced "non-Force-sensitive" offspring?

Comment: Are the "non-force-sensitive" offspring truly non-force-sensitive or is it just that their force sensitivity is so low that for all intents and purposes it's considered to be non-existent?

Answer (score 2):

In Canon, [Jacen Syndulla](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jacen_Syndulla), son of Jedi Knight [Kanan Jarrus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kanan_Jarrus) and non-Force-sensitive [Hera Syndulla](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hera_Syndulla) *may* not be a Force-sensitive; sufficient information is not available but no evidence for him being Force-sensitive has come forth as of yet.

In Legends, there are several examples of children of Force-sensitives who have no ability to use the Force, including:

- [Fionah Ti](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fionah_Ti), daughter of two Jedi.
- [Vaner Shan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vaner_Shan), son of two Jedi.
- [Theron Shan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Theron_Shan), brother of Vaner and likewise the son of two Jedi.

In Legends, one or more Force-sensitive parents producing non-sensitive offspring seems to be the exception to the rule, as most such relationships appear to produce Force-sensitive children.